# Hinted handoff in Cassandra (When the cluster cannot meet the consistency level specified by the client, Cassandra does not store a hint)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, consistency

I came across aforementioned line in blog 
http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_hh_c.html

Its quite confusing. So let's say I have **5 node cluster**, with **RF of 3** and **Write Consistency** as **Quorum** i.e. 2 nodes

Now, if I try to write something and out of three replica nodes for given particular data, two were down. So, does this mean that cassandra won't store hint (as it knows it won't be able meet given consistency of quorum in first place)? and reject that write right away OR it will store hint for them and give success in response?

Can someone please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different mechanics at hand here. Let me give you an example to clarify.

Assume I have a cluster of **3 nodes** with **3 replication** and consistency **Quorum(2)**.
This means that when I write to the database I will have to get two responses to satisfy my query.

After I satisfy my query, the node will have to send this write to the 3rd node. The node which has handled the query tries to send the write to the 3rd node. That node is currently unavailable, which causes the node to write a hinted handoff instead. Then it returns success to the client.

**Note** that hinted handoff happens after the consistency has been met. The hinted handoff makes sure that the write gets to all nodes which hold a replica.

Now there is **one exception to this** which is mentioned in the article you posted. **Consistency level ANY** is a consistency level that will be satisfied by writing a hinted handoff as long as there is a node which can serve the request.

Comment: So why do people say hinted handoff offer full write availability(https://www.datastax.com/blog/2012/12/modern-hinted-handoff) ? when CL is met, the write is ok even if we don't store hints.

Comment: Full write availability is the ability to write to your cluster even if nodes are down. Hinted handoff gives the ability to do so if you do not care about the consistency of your data. (That is the fact that the data isn't on all of your nodes)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a RF=3 and 2 nodes are down or unable to service the request in a timely manner then the write request will fail and the hinted handoff will not be stored.  Hinted handoffs will only be stored if the Consistency Level (CL) for the request can be met and you are within the hinted handoff window.  The only exception to this would be a request written with a CL=ANY.

Comment: If any node is unable to service the request in timely manner, then as per the documentation it will store hints. You said it won't store, why ?

Comment: Hints will only be stored if the write request is able to satisfy the specified consistency level (CL=QUORUM) in your case.  If <2 nodes are able to successfully write the request the request will fail and no hints will be stored.  If 2 nodes are able to satisfy the write then the hint will be stored for the 3rd node.  If all 3 replicas are able to write then no hints will be stored.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: So whenever I get **timeout exception** while writing. It means that it was not able to meet my consistency level and in that case hints won't be stored. Is it ?

Comment: please have a look at this blog http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-cassandra-deals-with-replica-failure. It says cassandra will maintain hinted handoff in above mentioned case.

Comment: Just to be clear here if you get a timeout exception from 1 node but the other 2 successfully write then a hinted handoff will be stored for the node which timed out.  However if you had 1 node down already (which is what I was thinking) and a second one has a timeout then the write will fail to meet the CL, a failed write will be sent to the client and no hinted handoff will be stored.  Sorry for the confusion and I should have been more clear in my earlier answer but this is pretty far down in the weeds as far as C* use cases go.